# Get date in a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone

i don't live in the pacific area and i am looking for a way to get the current day in the pacific area as my midnight does not match pacific midnight, how to do?

Current code

```
//how to set this to Pacific Time?
var timezone = new Date();

//get the current day
var day = timezone.getDate();

//use the day           
var row_for_day = day+3;
```

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it worked, it would be nice if you accepted it.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! I've taken the liberty of editing the question's title so other users may find it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this, using [Date#toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

(target timezone name can be looked up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

```js
const target = "America/Los_Angeles";

const laDate = +new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: target,  // conversion here
  day: "numeric"     // return day only
});

console.log("date in LA:", laDate);
```

I was looking for existing answers but wasn't able to find a good, current, concise fit. Point one out and I will remove this.