# Limit number range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the lacky explanation of my problem, but I am a beginner!

I have some code that converts time from base entered time zone to the users time zone. For example, when the user inputs a certain time in 15:00 BST - it automatically prints out 16:00 CEST for users in CEST time zone, or 10:00 EST in the EST time zone.

I run into a problem when it comes to Australia for example, the time zone is 9 hours ahead of BST and the display time for example
15:00 BST is 24:00 Australian time;
17:00 BST is 26:00 Australian time;

Can I somehow reset it to 0 when the number becomes 24? So when it's 26 it becomes 02?

Comment: Don't roll your own code for datetime related work, there are _way_ too many edge cases for your code to ever work (for example: BST is not 13 hours behind of Australia every day of the year, because of daylight savings rules, and even if you add that, _different parts_ of Australia have _different rules_ around that). Since you're using JS, use https://momentjs.com/ for this kind of thing, and make that do the conversion for you.

Comment: Here's how to let the browser do the conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007722/5734311

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree with "use a library" but Moment.js is advising against using Moment.js, so it's probably good to echo that, as well.

Comment: Reiterating what Mark0 said. The road to developer hell is paved with the skulls of those who tried to write their own datetime code. Avoid at all costs. I would recommend checking out date-fns as an alternative to moment.js.

Comment: Keep in mind that [**MomentJs**](https://momentjs.com/docs/) is in **maintenance mode**: *We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done.*

Comment: Noted. And for more information, see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ - the same advice of course still applies: do not write your own datetime code, but have a look at the newer solutions in JS land. Datetimes are the biggest mess, and any time you think you have a working rule, unless that rule is effectively a lookup through historical data as well as up to date formal declarations of timezones for the exact locales involved (a single city with its own timezone? you better believe it), you're already wrong.

Comment: Further to Mike's comment, I feel you need to watch this interesting discussion about timezones and programming: https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY tl;dr: just don't, use what already exists and move on, much more happily, in life.